# Guice injecting a generic list

Tags: java, swing, list, generics, guice

I would like to inject a list of various objects which differentiate with their generic type.

I have a MainView who accepts a list of ContentPanels (a subtype of Jpanel) which I want to display.

So i have

```
@Inject
MainView(List<ContentPanel<?>> contentPanel){
   ...
}
```

the content panels differ in their generic type, so there is one for books, one for a movie etc.

I tried to bind them with

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<AbstractContentPanel<Book>>(){})
        .to(new TypeLiteral<BookContentPanel<Book>>(){})
        .in(Singleton.class);
```

and

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<AbstractContentPanel<Movie>>(){})
            .to(new TypeLiteral<BookContentPanel<Movie>>(){})
            .in(Singleton.class);
```

but how can I make a list of them and inject them into my MainView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to inject all your *bindings* into a list, then you cannot do that. If you want to inject a list, you should bind it directly, like this:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<List<String>>() {})
  .toInstance(new ArrayList<String>());
```

But in this case your list must be known beforehand (or supplied via a `Provider`).

If you want to access your bindings through a sequence, you'll have to use [multibinding extension](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Multibindings). In that case your code could look like this:

```
Multibinder<ContentPanel<?>> multibinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), new TypeLiteral<ContentPanel<?>>() {});
multibinder.addBinding().to(YourContentPanelImpl1.class);
multibinder.addBinding().to(YourContentPanelImpl2.class);
// and so on
```

And then you can inject a `Set`:

```
@Inject
MainView(Set<ContentPanel<?>> contents) {
    ...
}
```